# Excel problems with axes data labels in dual clustered column chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a dual clustered chart and I need to format the two Y axes, so they show a currency sign after the value but only on the highest value - not every single one.

What do I need to put into the Custom Format? I've just overlaid a text box for now so you can see what I mean, though the client doesn't want that!

Also, I can't work out how to Centre the x-axis years underneath the two clustered columns. Any ideas (highlighted)?

[image: Clustered chart axes]

Answer (score 1):

**Custom format for axes**
Unfortunately, it is not possible to format the largest value separately (unless using VBA code), you can only format values above a certain limit separately. In this case, you can use the following format codes:

```
[>6]0.0"%";0.0
[>140][$$-en-US]0;0
```

**x-axis labels**
You must manipulate with `Series Overlap` and `Gap Width`. I have used the following settings. Order of series: `Series 1` (col. B), primary; `Serie3` (col. C), primary; `Serie2` (col. C), secondary; `Series 2` (col. D), secondary.
Primary axis: series overlap 33%, gap width 100%; secondary axis: overlap -33%, gap width 50%.
[image: Clustered_chart]